# Eclipse No Such Element Exception

Tags: eclipse

While I am working on eclipse this error keep displaying on the screen

`An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tool tip" java.util. No Such Element Exception`

When I try to close eclipse I get the same error message and eclipse won't close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529629/eclipse-an-internal-error-occurred-during-compute-launch-button-tooltip)

Comment: Check in the error log("Windows > Show View > Error Log") if you can find an entry for this with a full stack trace.